# How to translate the user profile page in commerce kickstart

Tags: i18n-l10n, commerce

Hello,
I'm using commerce kicksart in my website, I use french as source language instead of english, I translated many words in the user profile page, but I can't translate or edit some titles:

-HELLO
-PRIMARY SHIPPING ADDRESS
-PRIMARY BILLING ADDRESS
-RECENT ORDERS

[image]
I didn't find them in the translate interface page admin/config/regional/translate/translate, also I didn't find any view or block to edit them.

How I can translate or edit them without touch the tpl file?

Thanks

Comment: I think I already fixed this issue, I'm trying to remember how I did, so I'll put it here as comment.and sure I'll try your solution too

Comment: it's just because the language problem I don't share my research results, it's diffuclt to explain to experienced people. another thing I'm working in many projects -so busy-, I'm seeking to find time to spend it here in stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in [issue #1937982](https://www.drupal.org/node/1937982) has been used to solve an issue similar to yours. That issue includes a .PO file to handle at least these strings:

- Primary billing address
- Primary shipping address

If that would work in your case also, you can probably use the same solution by adding 2 similar lines for these 2 other strings (you may have to verify if it is case sensitive or not):

- HELLO
- RECENT ORDERS